# Azure per user Budget

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In Azure cloud can we set Budget for each of our developers. I mean if my developer is creating x,y,z resources in Azure can he be restricted to some amount limit? If NOT each user can this be done for a UserGroup or ResourceGroup?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.
How?

here is a list of steps to follow:

Set Azure spending budget

Sign in to the Portal and go to cost management and spending

-Create a budget for your user.

Enter a value for Monthly budget.

[image]

Choose Apply to save your changes.

On the customer's Subscriptions page, under Usage-based subscription, choose Change budget.

Enter a value for the budget.

Choose Apply to save your changes.

I would suggest to use departments to make it more easy to understand.